# Regex to match GGG and number after GGG

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to build a regex to match GGG and number after GGG (might me with space) for example:

```
This is GGG 15
This is GGG15
```

Comment: How about: `GGG\h*\d+`

Comment: What if your string contains `BGGG`, do you want that matched too?

Comment: @ctwheels no sir

Comment: @Toto, I have an error "Unrecognized escape sequence \h" in C# code. what is \h in your code?

Comment: Then use `\bGGG *\d+` or `\bG{3} *\d+`

Comment: Replace `\h*` with `\s*` or ` *`

Comment: @ctwheels - create an answer! Your tested - worked for me!

Comment: @Vnuuk there are other good answers that are very close to what I wrote above. You can accept one of those answers instead :)

Comment: @Toto what is \h?  What language uses that?

Comment: @ysth: `\h` stands for horizontal white space, it works for PCRE

Answer (score 2):

first thing that comes to my mind:

```
@"\bGGG\s*\d+"
```

explanation :

`\b` word boundary
`\s*` whitespace occuring 0 or more times (makes the space optional)
`\d+` digit occuring 1 or more times (makes the number mandatory, at least 1 digit)

Answer (score 1):

This should just be:

```
\bGGG ?\d+
```

or if you want to allow any whitespace, not just a space character:

```
\bGGG\s?\d+
```

or if you want to allow more than one whitespace character:

```
\bGGG\s*\d+
```

From the comments, the \b is necessary to exclude `BGGG123`.  If you also want to exclude something like `GGG123B`, also add a `\b` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**: `\w+\s*\d+` or if it's only `GGG` then use `GGG\s*\d+`

**Details**:

`\w` Matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])

`+` Matches between one and unlimited times

`\s` Matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])

`*` Matches between zero and unlimited times

`\d` Matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u8UOvJ/3)

Answer (score 0):

Vnuuk,

Sorry the slashes are backwards, it should be GGG\s+\d+.

Answer (score -1):

One of the resources I use is https://regexr.com/ to help when I am working on getting my regex's correct.

You could use GGG/s+/d+

Comment: That regular expression definitely does not do what OP is asking (especially since `/s` isn't even a special sequence)

Comment: `/s`, `/d` are invalid and even if `/s` did match something, you use the `+` quantifier, which means at least one whitespace character must be present and the OP specified that the spaces are optional

Comment: Invalid is a strong word I used... They're not invalid, but they're not tokens. This regex may, in fact, be invalid assuming the delimiter is `/`, but C# doesn't use that, so it's not invalid, but your *"tokens"* aren't tokens.